# How to use rsync command on CentOS through specific port?

Tags: linux, centos, rsync

I'm currently learning about linux server administration and I'm using CentOS but I'm stuck. So far my command goes like this `rsync -avz backup/ user@192.168.1.20:Desktop/backup/`. I have established an ssh connection with the remote server in another terminal, I just can't figure out how to specify a port to use with the ip, for example say I forwarded port 1001.

I have tried

```
rsync -avz backup/ user@192.168.1.20:-p1001:Desktop/backup/
rsync -avz backup/ user@192.168.1.20::1001:Desktop/backup/
rsync --port=1001 -avz backup/ user@192.168.1.20:Desktop/backup/
```

I expect the remote server asking me for a password, after I type it in the files should transfer to the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rsync -av -e 'ssh -p 1001' backup/ user@192.168.1.20:Desktop/backup/
```

This would ask `rsync` to use `ssh` to connect to port 1001 on the remote system.

See also the documentation for `-e` and `--rsh` in the `rsync` manual (which contains more information and examples).

Comment: Thank you so much @Kusalananda this worked on the first try, but it seems that the person who made this course had no idea what it's like outside his basement. Now I have to sync files from the remote server to my local machine... So the command I'm suppose to use is `rsync -av -e 'ssh -p 1001' user@192.168.1.20:Desktop/remotebackup/ Desktop/localbackup/` but the output is `rsync: mkdir "/home/Desktop/remotebackup/Desktop/localbackup" failed: No such file or directory`

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, my command should look like this `rsync -arvz -e 'ssh -p 1001' user@192.168.1.20:Desktop/remotebackup/ Desktop/localbackup/`

Comment: @FSmit There are no functional differences between your two commands. The `-r` flag is implicit when you use `-a` and `-z` is seldom needed (only when the speed of compression/decompression is much higher than the bandwidth of the network).

Comment: So far it only worked with the `-r` flag. I'll do a bit more research on why it kept saying `mkdir`... and `skipping directories`.

Comment: @FSmit Yes, do that. The path `/home/Desktop/remotebackup/Desktop/localbackup` in the error message doesn't even make sense.